# error in C language user defined function defination

Tags: c

I am getting one error in C code of Linux device driver code of a i2c slave device.
Here is a function definition:

```
static char *read_temperature() 
{   
    static char arr[5];
    .....
    .....
    return arr;
}
```

***Error:***
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘static’
static char *read_temperature() {

If you know the solution to resolve this then please help me.
In same code file this error I am getting for every function whose return type is static.

Comment: What kind of device does this target? Microcontroller? What compiler do you use? You should add as much information as possible.

Comment: Btw it's probably better to use `void` in the params list, i.e. `static char *read_temperature(void)`. Most likely you're mixing C and C++ and this is outside extern C or inside some other contruct. Is it a header file?

Comment: "expected specifier-qualifier-list before..." Probably means that you have a syntax error before this function.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what is located before that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static` before a function declaration doesn't say  that the return value is static. It says that the function is static to the compilation unit (it cannot be accessed by other .c files). You can just delete the static and stay with `char *read_temperature()`. Returning something that is static is no different from returning something that is global.

This probably is not your error (it can be that you wanted your function to be static, i just assumed you didn't). i think some code before the function declaration is the culprit.

The `expected specifier-qualifier-list before` usually says that you are using a type that you didn't define yet, which is strange in this case. it basically says that you are using a new type `static` inside a struct. we need more code before and after the function to know for sure

Comment: This should go into a comment as it does not really answer the question. (which is barely possible without seeing more code). In Linux drivers it is not uncommon to keep all the internal stuff `static`. Therewore I think it is safe to assume that `static` really is intented here.

Comment: yeah, i couldn't comment at that time :D

Comment: That does not really serve as an excuse. Wrapping comments into answers that really don't answer anything is abusing the answer system and should be avoided.